# Parse Array-like string as Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have this JavaScript string that contains and array of malformed JSON and I would like to parse it as the array it represents. The string goes:

`variable = [{ var1: 'value11', var12: 'value2', var3: 'value13' }, { var1: 'value21', var2: 'value22', var3: 'value23' }]`

Is it possible to parse this so that it becomes an actual array?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: The solution to this is going to be extremely dependent on what language you plan to use. Please edit your question to explain that.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. It's been added to the OP just in case.

Comment: Why is the "JSON" malformed at all?

Comment: It comes from coding I have no authority over. I can only work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `variable =` is also returned as part of the string, so correct me if I'm wrong.

If you're using JavaScript, you can eval that, and then use it. Unfortunately this does mean that you're stuck with that variable name though.

http://jsfiddle.net/2xTmh/

Comment: Thank you! I don't mind sticking with that variable name, it's not an issue. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using php, you could "fix" the json string with regular expressions. This works:

```
<?php 
$json = "variable = [{ var1: 'value11', var12: 'value2', var3: 'value13' }, { var1: 'value21', var2: 'value22', var3: 'value23' }]";
// replace 'variable =' with '"variable" :' and surround with curly braces
$json = preg_replace('/^(\S+)\s*=\s*([\s\S]*)$/', '{ "\1" : \2 }', $json);
// quote keys and change to double quotes
$json = preg_replace("/(\S+): '(\S+)'/", '"\1": "\2"', $json);
echo $json . "\n";

$data = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($data);
?>
```

This outputs:

```
{ "variable" : [{ "var1": "value11", "var12": "value2", "var3": "value13" }, { "var1": "value21", "var2": "value22", "var3": "value23" }] }
Array
(
    [variable] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [var1] => value11
                    [var12] => value2
                    [var3] => value13
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [var1] => value21
                    [var2] => value22
                    [var3] => value23
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks and yes, php would make it easier... unfortunately it's not an option.